# Dynamic reference to resource files in C#

Tags: c#, localization

I have an application on which I am implementing localization.

I now need to dynamically reference a name in the resouce file.

assume I have a resource file called Login.resx, an a number of strings: foo="hello", bar="cruel" and baz="world"

normally, I will refer as: 
String result =Login.foo;
and result=="hello";

my problem is, that at code time, I do not know if I want to refer to foo, bar or baz - I have a string that contains either "foo", "bar" or "baz".

I need something like:

Login["foo"];

Does anyone know if there is any way to dynamically reference a string in a resource file?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You'll need to instance a [`ResourceManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984408%28VS.71%29.aspx) for the `Login.resx`:

```
var resman = new System.Resources.ResourceManager(
    "RootNamespace.Login",
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
)
var text = resman.GetString("resname");
```

It might help to look at the generated code in the code-behind files of the resource files that are created by the IDE. These files basically contain readonly properties for each resource that makes a query to an internal resource manager.

Comment: Or even easier, you can just access the `ResourceManager` on the resource itself. e.g. Login.ResourceManager.GetString("foo")

Answer (score 2):

If you put your Resource file in the App_GlobalResources folder like I did, you need to use

> global::System.Resources.ResourceManager
>   temp = new
>   global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("RootNamespace.Login",
>   global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));

It took me a while to figure this out. Hope this will help someone. :)