# Dynamically call localized string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, resx

I have two resx file (language.resx and language.ne.resx). Call localized string by razor syntax

```
@language.Sports
```

I have string to be changed to corresponding localized string which is retrieved from database. The corresponding data is used as string in resx resources file.
how can I assign string dynamically e.g.

```
foreach (var item in cat)
{
    language.item.CategoryName; //error
}
```

How can I call the localized string dynamically?

Comment: 'language' does not contain a definition for 'item'

Comment: I found the solution for this I need the ResourceManager instance. Same question at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845/dynamic-reference-to-resource-files-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

What's the type of Item ?

Also can you not just do something like the following?

```
foreach (var item in cat)
{
    language[item].CategoryName;
}
```

Comment: item and cat type is Category table object  which have CategoryName and CategoryName have Sports, Entertaintment etc. and language is resources file.